# iphone sharedAccelerometer memory failure

Tags: iphone, ios4, memory-management

I have a fundamental iPhone memory management question.

I have an object with a property of a UiAccelerator:
.h:

```
@interface AccelerationController : NSObject <UIAccelerometerDelegate> 
{
    UIAccelerometer *accelerometer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIAccelerometer *accelerometer;
```

.m:

```
self.accelerometer = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
self.accelerometer.updateInterval = .5;
self.accelerometer.delegate = self;
```

WHen I release an instantiation of AccelerationController, dealloc is called.

```
- (void)dealloc 
{  self.accelerometer.delegate = nil; // WORKS
   // self.accelerometer = nil;     WHY DOES THIS BLOW UP THE PROGRAM?
   //[self.accelerometer release]; CANT DO THIS BECAUSE WE NEVER ALLOCATED IT
   [super dealloc];
}
```

I dont understand why the first line of the dealloc function works but the second doesent. self.accelerometer is a pointer. You should be able to set a pointer to null. However, it fails with BAD_ACCESS, almost like its trying to set the sharedAccelerometer to nil.

Can someone explain to me why the top is correct and the second is incorrect? (I know why the third line fails)

Comment: You use a property to access `self.accelerometer`.

Comment: Furthermore, If I just leave dealloc blank, its like it tries to release the accelerometer anyway, AND the program blows up with BAD_ACCESS

Comment: You might want to look at this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044421/using-self-on-ivars-in-dealloc/4044731#4044731

Answer (score 0):

Your `accelerometer` property doesn’t need to be declared as `retain`: you’re not taking ownership of the shared accelerometer when you use it, so you’re not responsible for holding onto that reference. With the property declared as `retain`, calling `self.accelerometer = nil` implicitly releases the property’s old value; it would seem that the UIAccelerometer instance ignores the implicit `-retain` message but does not ignore the `-release`, hence the EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Switch the property to `assign` and you should no longer see that crash.